# getContainer in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to get a block from a twig template them render it to my index template:

```
{% block round1 %}
<h1> hello this is a sample for a round 1</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block round2 %}
<h1> hello this is a sample for a round 1</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

then get it to my controller using

```
  use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
  use Alvin\MainBundle\Entity\User;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
  use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
  use Alvin\MainBundle\Form\Type\ResetPasswordType;

 
  $templateContent = $this->getContainer()->get('twig')->loadTemplate('AngpaoMainBundle:Dynamic:dynamic.html.twig');
  $bodydynamics = $templateContent->renderBlock('round1');
```

then use it in my index template

```
{{dynamic}}
```

but then im having a problem and symfony says

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method 
Alvin\MainBundle\Controller\IndexController::getContainer() in /Users/alvinvaldez/Sites/alvinwebsite/src/Alvin/MainBundle/Controller/IndexController.php line 26
```

I dont know what to use to get the container running.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no `getContainer()` method for a controller.

You could access it by `$this->container` directly like `$this->container->get('twig')`

But Symfony provide shortcut method for controller, you could use `$this->get('twig')` too.

Comment: yeah but a new problem arise Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Twig_Template::renderBlock() must be of the type array,

Comment: ＠Aoi Yes, you should provide an array as the parameter.

Comment: yeah i just pass an empty array like $bodydynamics = $templateContent->renderBlock('round1', array()); but then in my index template the dynamics came out like this: 
<div class="top-black-border"></div>
     " <h1>hello this is a sample for a round 1 </h1>"

Comment: i found an answer {{ dynamic | raw }}